# Как вывести определенное количество записей в обратной зависимости?

Tags: php

```
<?php
  $cat = mysqli_query($link,
    "SELECT DISTINCT `category` FROM `news` ORDER BY `category` ASC"
  );
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat)){
?>
<a href="#">
<?php 
  if(mysqli_num_rows($cat) <= 5){
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['category']);
  }else{
```

Надо вывести 4 строки из базы данных, затем вместо 5 строки подставить

```
   <a href="#">all</a>
  }
?>
</a>
```

Нужно чтобы до превышения 5 штук ссылка не выводилась, а при превышении 5 строка заменялась. Может кто знает решение? LIMIT не дает решения

Comment: счетчик внутрь while всунь и проверяй его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `mysqli_num_rows()` возвращает общее число строк в выборке и Вам она не нужна. Вам нужно запросить 6 строк из базы (`LIMIT 6`) вывести первые 4, а пятую вывести только если есть шестая. Чтобы знать сколько строк уже выведено, нужно завести счетчик

```
$cat = mysqli_query($link,
  "SELECT DISTINCT `category` FROM `news` ORDER BY `category` LIMIT 6"
);
$idx = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat)) {
  $idx++;
  echo '<a href="#">';
  // если вывели меньше пяти строк или нет шестой
  if ($idx < 5 || !mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat))
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['category']);
  else
    echo "all";
  echo '</a>';
}
```

Comment: @Юрий Изменил ответ

Comment: спасибо, теперь работает